# How to show suggessions after delay without pressing any key using jquery UI autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an input field and on entering three words I am ajaxing some data and creating an array using javascript. I want to make jQuery UI Autocomplete works with this array with a delay of 700. It is working but for showing suggestions I have to press one more key. While I wanted it to work without pressing any key. I want it to work as soon as delay completed. My code looks like:

```
$( "#CAT_Custom_283923" ).autocomplete({
   source: srvcsCitiesSafe, 
   delay: 3000 
});
```

[I have implemented it here](http://dbtrialsite.businesscatalyst.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.  The delay option is the delay between when a keystroke occurs and when your ajax search is performed. The code you have presented will do this correctly.

I am not sure what you mean by having to press one more key.  Once a keypress has been performed autocomplete will display a list of items that match.  You can set autoFocus to true, this will select the first item in the list for you.  See example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Jquery UI Auto complete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">
            Tags:
        </label>
        <input id="tags" />
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()
    {
        var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
        ];
        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            delay: 1000,
            autoFocus: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ajax performed on keyup event when string length is '1', when data loaded we initialize the autocomplete() but than we need to press one more char so autocomplete show drop down. What I have done is I restrict user to enter third char untill ajax loaded. But this is not a good way to do it. Idealy it will show once data is loaded without entering more char.